# Ошибка скрипта, после переноса с JavaScript на PHP

Tags: javascript, html, php

Вот скрипт. Раньше работал на javascript, пересинтаксил на PHP, и теперь не работает

```
<?php 
    $Mass1 = ["", "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z", "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z", ""];
  for ($e = 1; $e < 64; $e++) {
        for ($d = 1; $d < 64; $d++) {
            for ($c = 1; $c < 64; $c++) {
                for ($b = 1; $b < 64; $b++) {
                    for ($a = 1; $a < 64; $a++) {
                        for ($l = 1; $l < 64; $l++) {
                            for ($i = 1; $i < 64; $i++) {
                                for ($n = 1; $n < 64; $n++) {
                                    echo $Mass1["i"] . $Mass1["l"] . $Mass1["n"] . $Mass1["a"] . $Mass1["b"] . $Mass1["c"] . $Mass1["d"] $Mass1["e"];
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

Должен выводить случайные значения. Почините, пожалуйста, или подскажите где ошибки, а то не работает, очень плохо... Буду благодарен и поблагодарю очками

Comment: Welcome to http://govnokod.ru/!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
<?php $Mass1 = array("", "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z", "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z", ""); 
for ($e = 1; $e < 64; $e++)
    for ($d = 1; $d < 64; $d++)
        for ($c = 1; $c < 64; $c++)
            for ($b = 1; $b < 64; $b++)
                for ($a = 1; $a < 64; $a++)
                    for ($l = 1; $l < 64; $l++)
                        for ($i = 1; $i < 64; $i++)
                            for ($n = 1; $n < 64; $n++)
                                echo $Mass1[$i].$Mass1[$l].$Mass1[$n].$Mass1[$a].$Mass1[$b].$Mass1[$c].$Mass1[$d].$Mass1[$e]; 
?>
```

Вроде так